# Android Post to API Doesn't Work, Ajax Post Works OK. Required String parameter 'firstname' is not present"

Tags: javascript, java, android, ajax, spring

I have a Spring Framework API setup to receive GET/POST request which works fine over the web however when trying to post from Android, I get a "Required String parameter 'firstname' is not present".

I've tried to post using different iterations but continually get the same error.

Java Spring Framework

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/addUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addUser(@RequestParam(value="firstname") String firstname,
                      @RequestParam(value="lastname") String lastname,
                      @RequestParam(value="username") String username,
                      @RequestParam(value="password") String password) throws Exception {
    String success = add.addUser(firstname, lastname, username, password);
    return toJson(success);
}
```

Javascript Version

```
var data = {
        firstname: firstname,
        lastname: lastname,
        username : username,
        password : password
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "<url removed>/import/addUser",
        success: function(data) {
            callbackSuccess(JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        error: function(data) {
            callbackFail(data);
        },
        data: data,
        dataType: "json"
    });
```

Android

```
        String url = "<url removed>/import/addUser";
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = "";
                try {
                    // 1. create HttpClient
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                    // 2. make POST request to the given URL
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                    String json = "";
                    // 3. build jsonObject
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                    jsonObject.accumulate("firstname", userFirstName);
                    jsonObject.accumulate("lastname", userLastName);
                    jsonObject.accumulate("username", emailStr);
                    jsonObject.accumulate("password", passwordStr);

                    // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
                    json = jsonObject.toString();

                    // 5. set json to StringEntity
                    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);

                    // 6. set httpPost Entity
                    httpPost.setEntity(se);
                    Log.i("Sending", json);
                    // 7. Set some headers to inform server about the type of the content
                    httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                    httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

                    // 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

                    // 9. receive response as inputStream
                    inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

                    // 10. convert inputstream to string
                    if(inputStream != null)
                        result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
                    else
                        result = "Did not work!";

                Log.i("Response", result);
```

Any thoughts or suggestions?

**UPDATE**
I have since modified the Spring Framework code so that the parameters are not required and I am not receiving any values. Only null as the variables. So it does look like there's an issue with the POST itself rather than server side.

Comment: Did you try `@RequestParam(value="firstname" , required = false) String firstname` ?

Answer (score 0):

Content-type should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. See this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13055885/spring-not-accepting-a-post-parameter-unless-requestparam-required-false) it helped me once

Comment: Mhhh! Let's try something other! Set content-type on se `se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));`